# Hey guys, I have a problem in my code, those *ELSE* and *PRINT* are with an issue, but I don't know what it is, can anyone help me?

Tags: python

```
import random
print('\033[33m--------Jogo de Par ou Ímpar--------\033[m')
r1 = input('Par ou Ímpar? '.lower().strip())
r2 = random.choice(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
resultado = 0
while True:
    if (r1 + r2) % 2 == 0:
        print('''O resultado foi Par
    sua jogada:{}
jogada do computador{}'''.format(r1,r2))
        resultado = 'par'
        if resultado == r1:
            print('\033[32mVocê VENCEU!\033[m')
        else:
            print('\033[31mVocê PERDEU, FIM DE JOGO\033[m')
            break
    print('=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')
    *ELSE:*
        *PRINT*('''O resultado foi Ímpar
    sua jogada:{}
jogada do computador{}'''.format(r1,r2))
        if resultado == r1:
            print('\033[32mVocê VENCEU!\033[m')
        else:
            print('\033[31mVocê PERDEU, FIM DE JOGO\033[m')
            break
    print('=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')
```

also my pycharm shows 4 error messages
Statement expected, found Py:ELSE_KEYWORD:18
Statement expected, found Py:COLON:18
Unexpected indent:19
Statement expected, found Py:DEDENT:27

Comment: The `print` *before* the `else` must either be removed or indented to be part of the preceding `if` block.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's time to solve the many other problems